# Dúvida em cliente para uma webapi

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax, asp.net-core

Estou com uma leve dúvida... conclui uma webapi em asp.net core, já está toda testada e tudo mais , porém, me surgiu uma dúvida... Inclui um novo projeto junto a essa api, de forma a ser a cliente que irá consumir de tal api e queria saber o seguinte, como faço para apontar para o endereço onde a minha api está levantada? Obs: queria utilizar html com requisições AJax mas se tiverem uma dica de um front end para consumir e enviar json, deixem recomendação!

Comment: consumiria a api em javascript, acho mais ideal